# Symfony2 logout issue2

Tags: symfony

Mys security.yml is given bellow..

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: AcmeHelloBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
     secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/ual_courses
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /ual
        http_basic: ~     

access_control:
    - { path: ^/ual_courses, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

When I try logout using 
"xyz.com/symfonyproject/test/web/app_dev.php/logout" it doesn't logout and showing error message "No route found for "GET /logout". where is the problem ??

Routing.yml

```
    acme_hello_test:
    path:  /ual
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index}
acme_hello_static:
    path: /privacy
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: 'AcmeHelloBundle:Static:privacy.html.twig'
acme_hello_redirect:
    path: /redirect
    defaults: {_controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:change}

AcmeHelloBundle_ual_courses:
        resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing/courses.yml"
        prefix:   /ual_courses

logout:
   path:   /logout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Symfony are you running ? You need to define a specific /logout route since 2.1

> *Note that you will not need to implement a controller for the /logout URL as the firewall takes care of everything. You do, however, need to create a route so that you can use it to generate the URL*

See [this paragraph of symfony firewall documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out) for more information.

**Edit**

Make sure your logout route is behind the firewall. See the [avoid common pitfall](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls) of the cookbook.

Your firewall only catches patterns starting with /ual_courses, thus doesn't include /logout. Try with :

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/*
    #http_basic: ~
```

Notice the http_basic commented out.

Comment: Hi I am using symfony 2.4.1 and add path logout in app/config routing.yml file 
logout:
    pattern: /logout    now it showing following error   Unable to find the controller for path "/logout". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration

Comment: Replace "pattern" with "path" in your app/config/routing.yml file

Comment: Can you add your routing.yml file in your post? And is it the full version of your secutiry.yml file?

Comment: Thanks.. Its working.. but there is another problem. User does not un-authenticate. after logout, I can access control area. it doesn't ask for username and password

Comment: Your firewall is probably not covering what you expect it to cover anymore. Change its pattern back to : ^/uas_courses but then change the logout path to /uas_courses/logout